# W3C Validation - Wordpress DOC Type

Tags: css, wordpress, validation, w3c

i submitted the following site for validation, and received this error:

[Website Link](http://run-time.co.za/testing)

Error:

```
No DOCTYPE found! Checking with default XHTML 1.0 Transitional Document Type.

No DOCTYPE Declaration could be found or recognized in this document. This generally means that the document is not declaring its Document Type at the top. It can also mean that the DOCTYPE declaration contains a spelling error, or that it is not using the correct syntax.

The document was checked using a default "fallback" Document Type Definition that closely resembles “XHTML 1.0 Transitional”.
```

I have tried changing the DOC type to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

however it still picks up the error?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Add just `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a doc type at the top of your source code. I have added one and manually validated the code through the [W3 checker](http://validator.w3.org/check) and it passed without warning to related to the doc type.

This is the doc type I added

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```